# Move in and Move to

Tags: grammar

my question is simple, if in a sentence like "everyone is dreaming to move ... the US" what's the right word between "in" and "to"?

Is move IN totally wrong in this case? 
I'm sorry if this question has been already asked and I know It's stupid but I need clarification :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would say, , "Everyone dreams of moving to..." That's how I hear it in SoCal.
Shana

Comment: This would be improved if you say why this form is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The verb you're using ("move") indicates a sequence / process. These verbs usually use "to" or "into".

Answer (score 1):

You move *into* a house, but *to* a different city or country.